# SQL Query Multiple Columns Using Distinct on One Column Only and Using Order By

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to select all the distinct names from a column and order them by another column, sort_order.

I've tried several things:

```
select distinct ( name ), sort_order from table1  where active=1 order by sort_order
```

The above code outputs two columns, however, some repeat names have different sort_order values and still appear.

```
select name, sort_order from table1 where
name in (Select min(name) FROM table1 where active=1  group by sort_order )
```

The above code produces the error message:

*The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP, OFFSET or FOR XML is also specified.*    
     I tried replacing the order by with a group by, but this produces the list in the wrong order.

```
select distinct name as flavors from table1 where active=1 order by sort_order
```

The above code produces the error message: 
   *ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified.*

I need the name column to display all distinct names and the sort_order column should display all the corresponding sort_order numbers (some may repeat).

Comment: If in the table a specific name appears in 2 rows with 2 different sort_orders which one do you want in the results?

Comment: Which ever appears first in the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use aggregation:

```
select name, max(sort_order)
from z_mflavs 
where active = 1
group by name
order by max(sort_order);  -- or min() or avg()
```

Note that in your query, the parentheses around `(name)` are utterly superfluous.  `SELECT DISTINCT` is a clause in the SQL language and it applies to *all* columns being selected, regardless of whether any are expressions in parentheses.

Answer (score 1):

Use this query...if you want values of name, sort_order column

```
  SELECT name, MAX(sort_order) as sort_order  FROM table1 
               Group by name ORDER BY MAX(sort_order) DESC
```